# Extract the list from Min expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm using `Simplify` over a Min of a finite list in order to get rid of unobserved cases.

As a result, after the simplify I see

```
Min[1/29 (39 + 74 p1), 1/23 (29 + 78 p1)]
```

(simplified, but it gets the point across) and I want to get store the list

```
1/29 (39 + 74 p1), 1/23 (29 + 78 p1)
```

as a variable.  Is there a built in function that would do this?

Comment: `a = List @@ Min[1/29 (39 + 74 p1), 1/23 (29 + 78 p1)] ` will do what you ask. However, doing it will mean that you never take the minimum of the two arguments.

Comment: `Min[1/29 (39 + 74 p1), 1/23 (29 + 78 p1)] /. Min -> List`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[p1_] = Piecewise[{{1/29 (39 + 74 p1),
    Reduce[1/29 (39 + 74 p1) < 1/23 (29 + 78 p1), p1]}},
  1/23 (29 + 78 p1)]
```

[image]